# Resharpening from the command line

Tags: resharper

I would like to use the ReSharper Adjust Namespaces feature on a number of solutions. I would like to automate this process by creating a command line application that uses the ReSharper API.

I looked at the ReSharper OpenAPI, but it seems to be geared towards using the ReSharper API from within an active Visual Studio session. I want to be able to use the ReSharper API from the command line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: the open API is generally geared towards use within VS. While using it outside of VS is theoretically possible, it is technically challenging and may or may not work depending on your usage scenario.

There's no reason, however, why you shouldn't be able to adjust namespaces across several solutions right from within Visual Studio - of course, this would require to actually load each solution into the shell before performing manipulations. As things stand, this approach is your best bet.