# Get all projects fron solution throws error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I am in debugging,
I got the reference to current solution as DTE2. ([as from "adabyron"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724381/get-the-reference-of-the-dte2-object-in-visual-c-sharp-2010))

I often got the following error when I tried foreach loop on vsSolution.Projects:

> The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

Click continue, I can still loop through all projects.
Any reason for me getting the error?

Comment: does it work if you retry that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it throws exception, but you can avoid it with `try catch`. It doesn't fail all the time. When fails you can retry it again and it works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580580/autoformat-code-from-command-line/15581025#15581025) is similar problem on my other post.