# What is the Visual Studio DTE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-sdk

I have been slowly digging through Visual Studio's SDK, but could not yet figure out what DTE stands for. This is a silly question, but I really can't seem to find it. DTE is super useful, it would be super cool to know what it is as well.

Comment: Here you may see some more stuff using DTE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580580/autoformat-code-from-command-line/15581025#15581025

Comment: This is useful, but doesn't define DTE I think.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It stands for Development Tools Environment.

They don't seem to mention it much, the only page on MSDN I could find that says what it stands for is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa301597%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Seems, that link isn't relevant anymore, is it?

Answer (score 9):

DTE = "Development Tools Environment"

Essentially, I understand it to be the part of Visual Studio that lets you interact with the computer itself. This can control things such as active windows and applications.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx):

> EnvDTE is an assembly-wrapped COM library containing the objects and members for Visual Studio core automation.