# version control over visual studio formatting style

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, stylecop

What's the way to go if I want to have a consistent style standard versioned? I want to achieve two things:

1. Pressing `ctrl-k,ctrl-f` (auto indenting) formats the code based on a shared standard
2. Stylecop runs against shared rules

What files do I have to add in my git repository to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`pre-commit` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks).

You can version in your git repo a hook script (say `pre-commit.sh`) at the root of your project and include the installation instructions in your `README/documentation` to encourage all developers use it.

Installation is nothing more than:

```
ln -s ../../pre-commit.sh .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

As the article "[Tips for using a git pre-commit hook](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/)", you need, in that hook, to ensure that **code that isn't part of the prospective commit isn't tested within your pre-commit script**:

```
# pre-commit.sh
git stash -q --keep-index

# Test prospective commit
# call format, stylecop...

git stash pop -q
```

Comment: That's all very interesting, I always promised myself to learn more about pre-commits, but I don't see how it addresses poinst **1** and **2**

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue because the committed version would auto-indent, and run stylecop: if stylecop fails, the commit won't be completed.

Comment: Do you know what's the best way to auto indent c# code?

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue you can try calling stylecop with http://sourceforge.net/projects/stylecopcli/. And you can call your format tool (like Resharper) from a decicated command: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15580580/6309. You also can have a look at http://www.codemaid.net/

Comment: Thanks, I resolved not using the StyleCop cli but the Stylecop msbuild target. as per the autoformatting, I'll look into codemaid. Thnanks also for the idea about the hooks, I might implement one